# Unabe to parse large table in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table but Beautifulsoup only returns 60 elements, the table is considerably larger.
I tried scrolling to the bottom of the page(allowing the full table to load) and then parsing the HTML but it didn't work.

```
webdriver=webdriver.Chrome()
webdriver.get('https://www.bluenile.com/diamonds/round-cut')
WebDriverWait(webdriver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#diamond-result 
webdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
data=BeautifulSoup(webdriver.page_source,'html5lib')
shape=[]
price=[]
carat=[]
cut=[]
color=[]
clarity=[]
date=[]
table=data.find('div',{'class':'grid-body'})

data_shape=table.find_all('span',{'class':'single-cell'})
for items in data_shape:
    shape.append(items.getText())

data_price=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell price'}))

for items in data_price:
    price.append(items.getText())

data_carat=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell carat'}))

for items in data_carat:
    carat.append(items.getText())

data_cut=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell cut'}))

for items in data_cut:
    cut.append(items.getText())

data_color=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell color'}))

for items in data_color:
    color.append(items.getText())

data_clarity=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell clarity'}))

for items in data_clarity:
    clarity.append(items.getText())

data_date=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell date'}))

for items in data_date:
    date.append(items.getText())

print(str(shape))
print(str(price))
```

Comment: It should be that there are only 60 lines in your source code. Try adding a little delay to see if you can get the complete source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts fine.However since when you are scrolling the page to bottom it is taking some time to load data table data.You need to add some delay `time.sleep(5)`to get more records.With addition to that I am getting `510` records.

```
webdriver=webdriver.Chrome()
webdriver.get('https://www.bluenile.com/diamonds/round-cut')
WebDriverWait(webdriver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#diamond-result")))
webdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
#Added some delay
time.sleep(5)
data=BeautifulSoup(webdriver.page_source,'html5lib')
shape=[]
price=[]
carat=[]
cut=[]
color=[]
clarity=[]
date=[]
table=data.find('div',{'class':'grid-body'})

data_shape=table.find_all('span',{'class':'single-cell'})
for items in data_shape:
    shape.append(items.getText())

data_price=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell price'}))

for items in data_price:
    price.append(items.getText())

data_carat=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell carat'}))

for items in data_carat:
    carat.append(items.getText())

data_cut=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell cut'}))

for items in data_cut:
    cut.append(items.getText())

data_color=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell color'}))

for items in data_color:
    color.append(items.getText())

data_clarity=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell clarity'}))

for items in data_clarity:
    clarity.append(items.getText())

data_date=(table.find_all('div',{'class':'row-cell date'}))

for items in data_date:
    date.append(items.getText())

print(len(shape))
print(len(price))
```